# Kmeans: Crear gráfico con distribución de centroides

Tags: r

Siguiendo instrucciones (que no se explican) de un video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iy6-wxTRmcE), intento graficar la distribución de los centroides de cada grupo,obtenidos con k means, con el siguientes código :

```
> library(readxl)
> Ingresantes97 <- read_excel("Ingresantes97.xls")
> View(Ingresantes97)
> mini<-apply(Ingresantes97[,c(2,6,10,24,25)],2,min)
> maxi<-apply(Ingresantes97[,c(2,3,4,5,7)],2,max)
> maxi<-(as.numeric(maxi))
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> mini<-(as.numeric(mini))
> centersde<-t(mini+t(centers)*(maxi-mini))
Error in t(centers) * (maxi - mini) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

**NO entiendo el error.**

Comment: ¿De dónde sale `centers`? Por otro lado el mensaje de error lo que te dice es que no puedes multiplicar cuando una de las partes no es numérica, imagino que es lo que le pasa a `t(centers)`

Comment: Centers son los centroides que se obtienen aplicando el algoritmo kmeans:

Comment: Me imaginaba, pero en tu código no esta invocando a `kmeans()` en ningún lugar y además, `centers` debiera ser una de las propiedades del modelo, por lo que en realidad, imagino, debieras acceder mediante `modelo$centers`

Comment: Corregí ese error y ahora me aparece lo siguiente:> parcoord(data_centers,col=1:5,var,label=TRUE)
Error in rep_len(lty, k) : attempt to replicate non-vector
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: In min(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Comment: Copié mal la instrucción, lo correcto es escribir:>parcoord(data_centers,col=1:5,var.label=TRUE). Me orientó lograr que este código funcione, la explicación del anterior error. Muchas gracias